# How to deal with hidden edges

Tags: edges

How do you guys generally deal with BAD hidden edges in Blender when working with animated character meshes? For example, I have a couple of them on my character's low-poly elbow that look terrible because of the hidden edge orientation - the edges sink deep into the elbow when it bends. It is so extreme, it looks like a mech arm when bent.

Do you guys convert these problem areas into triangles (which usually requires converting them back before sub-division) to have full control over the orientation? Or do you reshape the topology to make the area better? Or do you just ignore the problems?

I've been trying the second option (reshaping), but have spent more time than is probably worth on 8 vertices. Anyone have any tricks or is there an obvious solution I don't know about? I used Max in the past. And for that, we could just flip the edges. But it was still sometimes a problem during export/conversion.

Thanks for any suggestions!

[image: Elbow polygon]

Comment: Hard to say as you don't show any screenshots with examples. First make sure that the Armature modifier is above the Subsurf, and activate the Preserve Volume option in this modifier. Maybe you can fix your problem with a better topology, or with some shape keys and drivers, but again, please show some screenshots

Comment: I only use sub-division for baking purposes. To create a base mesh for sculpting details. But that isn't the only issue that stems from using triangles. There's also loop workflow and such that makes things easy to manipulate with good edge flow. I was actually able to fix the problem for the moment, but I will post images as soon as I run into the same issue again. It happens often when working on low poly character models that will be exported as a game character.

Comment: For some reason, I seem to be able to actually rotate hidden edges now by temporarily converting them into triangles and back to quads. I was under the impression that Blender would randomly set the orientation, but that hasn't happened to any of them yet. I'm using the latest 2.8 release, so maybe they added something to hold those now.

Comment: hard to help you if you don't give any screenshots  ;)

Comment: Sure, I can show you. I managed to fix this specific situation by adjusting the edge flow to follow the elbow joint rotation better, but there are times when changing the edge flow to suit a specific rotation direction doesn't work, like in the hips and such, where they can rotate in any direction. I forced the situation in the image to show you what I meant, but my original problem was very similar. The highlighted (yellow) polygon is the one that is caving in during bending.

Comment: Robert, if you manage to model with only quads it's pro. Don't change that. But if you have issues when animating, and that your armature is well set, it means that the vertices are not in the appropriate position: how could you have the elbow curving well if the vertices follow the logic of the 3d mesh and not the logic of a real elbow ?